# Getting error 502 when using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've used the following method but failed because the connection was reset (error 502, said by Cr to be something about bad gateway and the server used as a proxy).

```
public IEnumerable<Station> GetStations()
{
  using (Context context = new Context())
    return context.Stations;
}
```

So I've verified that the following work. As expected, it did, so there's something fishy with my EF talking to the DB.

```
public IEnumerable<Station> GetStations()
{
  return new List<Station> { new Station() };
}
```

However, when I breakpoint the application upon the call, I see it bounce around nicely and I see the output consisting of all the stations (called Donkey and Monkey).

So I'm a bit confused because I can't see where the issue appears. Apparently, I **can return** a set of data like that. Apparently, I **can fetch** said data from the DB. What the duck (typo intended)?

I even tried to change everything to realized lists to exclude the possibility of lazy loading being the issue. To no avail...

The only weirdness I noticed is that the breakpoint's hit twice on a single load of the page. It doesn't tell me anything but it's the only thing I can think of that may lead to anything.

The work-around at the moment is to get the list of elements and then create new stations, based on the fetched ones. Please note - I can't to as follows.

```
List<Stations> stations = new List<Stations>();
using (Context context = new Context())
  foreach (Station station in context.Stations)
    stations.Add(station);
return stations;
```

I have to, surprisingly, to do create a whole new one and copy over its values property by property. Highly inconvenient and error-prone. Not to mention - hiding the issue!

```
List<Station> stations = new List<Station>();
using (Context context = new Context())
  foreach (Station station in context.Stations)
    stations.Add(new Station { A = station.A });
return stations;
```

After a log of digging I noticed that the type of elements in the returned list is *Station* in the working case but *Station_XXX...* as the tracker of EF keeps an eye on them. Can it be the issue? How to get rid of it the right way?

Comment: See if it changes if you call `return context.Stations.ToList()`

Comment: @leppie See the section about lazy loading. I'll try to make it even more clear - I've changed to *List<Station>* everywhere to exclude lazy loading. No difference.

Comment: It would seem the context (and entities) is being disposed before the response can be served. Just try the original without using `using`. In the end it will get GC'd after the request and you should not have issues. In a Winform application, you might even want to keep the context alive, but I assume this is web app.

Comment: @leppie Yupp, it's web application. However, I'm not sure that it's the context disposition, because the objects are added to a list outside the scope of *using* statement. Also, I've tried returning the original list directly from within the scope. The same problem there. Isn't there a smooth way to get rid of the trackiness and only obtain the underlying objects as POCOs? I've asked separately about it - you're welcome to give a shot [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458643/how-to-get-rid-of-the-suffix-on-object-names-added-by-ef).