# How to get rid of the suffix on object names added by EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I'm fetching a bunch of objects using EF and add them to the returned array, I noticed that the type provided to me by intellisense isn't just the name of the class. It also contains of a suffix, so that a class called *Donkey* looks like this.

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Donkey_9D8D...EB8F

I'd need it to be on the form belonging to my own namespace like so.

> FarmSpace.Donkey

How can I transform into that? One way is to build a replicator but I sense that there's a smarter way. Or at least an automatic approach to it.

The reason for it is that I get error 502 when I try returning the EF-donkeys but it seems to work if I donkey up my own objects. I've asked that in a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458347/getting-error-502-when-using-ef?noredirect=1#comment56659276_34458347) but haven't got much response on it (be that because of the holidays or something), so I'm trying to deploy the next best thing as a work-around.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, or why the EF proxies are a problem for you.  But if you really want to get rid of the proxies (at the expense of lazy loading and automatic change tracking), you can turn it off.

See [Working with Proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886) on how to do that and more.

> **Disabling proxy creation**
>
> Sometimes it is useful to prevent the Entity Framework from creating proxy instances. For example, serializing non-proxy instances is considerably easier than serializing proxy instances. Proxy creation can be turned off by clearing the `ProxyCreationEnabled` flag. One place you could do this is in the constructor of your context. For example:
>
> ```
> public class BloggingContext : DbContext 
> { 
>     public BloggingContext() 
>     { 
>         this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 
>     }  
>
>     public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
>     public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Well, I'm not saying that **this** is what I want to do, hehe. I'm saying that when I return the objects that are tracked (the ones with the suffixed tail in the class name) I get the error on the web page. When I actually create a copy (so that the objects have the shorter type), it works well. I'm fully open to resolve the issue so that returning the tracked version also works but I kind of got stuck there (see the linked question for details if you're feeling bold).

Comment: There's a linked entity in the *Station* pointing to *Records* and when I try to copy it as well, as I make a copy of the individual station, the issue reappeared. However, I used *Include* and that didn't improve anything...

Comment: I would love to help further, but somewhere behind that `502` that you're getting is an actual error message with a stack trace.  If you find that and post it here, it will be much easier to track down the actual cause of the problem and fix it appropriately.  In the meantime, turning off proxy creation can at the very least serve as a debugging tool to figure out if the problem is really related to proxies or not.